# How to share Uint8List image from Flutter web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm screenshotting one widget and have it as `Uint8List`.

Path provider and Share Plus doesn't support sharing files on web. Is anyone manage to share image as Uint8List from web?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if we could share the image but we can download an image with uint8List. Try the following

In index.html add this script

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/amcharts/3.21.15/plugins/export/libs/FileSaver.js/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
```

Use this in flutter

```js
import 'dart:html' as html; //ignore: avoid_web_libraries_in_flutter
import 'dart:js' as js;
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({
    Key ? key
  }): super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    Key ? key
  }): super(key: key);

  @override
  State < MyHomePage > createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State < MyHomePage > {
  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
  XFile ? image;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              InkWell(
                onTap: () async {
                  image = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
                },
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.upload,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                  height: 50,
                ),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    // Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
                    // String tempPath = tempDir.path;
                    // print(tempPath);
                    saveImg(await image!.readAsBytes(), "downloadImg.png");
                  },
                  child: const Text("SHARE"))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void saveImg(Uint8List bytes, String fileName) =>
  js.context.callMethod("saveAs", [
    html.Blob([bytes]),
    fileName
  ]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking to upload it to firebase and give user link but that was a solid solution.

Comment: That also didn't work. I tried sending an image with its url. You can send them a url though

Answer (score 1):

To download Uint8List as image on flutter web we need to create a function:

```
import 'dart:html' as html;
import 'dart:typed_data';

void downloadUint8ListAsImage(Uint8List imageBytes, String fileName) {
  final html.Blob blob = html.Blob([imageBytes], 'image/png');

  final String url = html.Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob);

  html.AnchorElement(href: url)
    ..setAttribute('download', fileName)
    ..click();

  html.Url.revokeObjectUrl(url);
}
```

and call it:

```
 ElevatedButton(
     onPressed: () {
        final Uint8List imageBytes = /* Your Uint8List here */;
        downloadUint8ListAsImage(imageBytes, 'example.png');
     },
     child: Text('download image'),
 )
```